# Divisibility of divisors in some tori and lattices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ and $E'$ be two general elliptic curves. We consider the $2$-dimensional torus $A:=\frac{E\times E'}{(u\times u')\left((\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2\right)}$, where $u:(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2\rightarrow E$ and $u':(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2\rightarrow E'$ are injective maps.

Now I want to find a basis for the Néron-Severi of the general $A$ of this kind ($\mathrm{NS}(A)$) in terms of $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{E'}$, the images of $E$ and $E'$ by this quotient, which I will call $\pi$. From projection formula, I know that $\bar{E}.\bar{E'}=\frac{1}{2}\pi^*\bar{E}.\pi^*\bar{E'}=4$ and this gives $\mathrm{NS}(A)\supset\langle\bar{E},\bar{E'}\rangle\simeq U(4)$, that is the lattice whose intersection matrix is given by $\begin{pmatrix} 0&4 \\ 4&0 \end{pmatrix}$. But I know from an other computation that $\mathrm{NS}(A)\simeq\langle2\rangle\oplus\langle-2\rangle$, which leads me to think that $\mathrm{NS}(A)=\langle\frac{\bar{E}+\bar{E'}}{2},\frac{\bar{E}-\bar{E'}}{2}\rangle$ (this would give the right lattice for $\mathrm{NS}(A)$).

**Question:** How to prove that $\bar{E}\pm\bar{E'}$ are divisible by $2$?

Comment: I'm not sure about your terminology, but shouldn't the answer depend on $E,E'$.  For example if $E= E'$ there is a 'diagonal class' of some sort in $NS(A)$.  If further $E = E'$ where $E$ has complex multiplication, shouldn't there also be a 'graph of the automorphism' class ?

Comment: @aginensky: The answer depends on the elliptic curves, but I'm looking at the general member of this family. In fact, for special cases that you mentionned, the Néron-Severi is not the same, but it can only get larger. Hence $\bar{E}\pm\bar{E'}$ should be divisible by $2$ anyway. I didn't want to get into the details of this in my question, but since I'm new to this site, do you think I should?

Comment: I'm agnostic as to whether you should explain more or replace 'E' with 'general E'. I'm not an expert on this site.  I was mainly pointing out that your statement about the equality of NS(A) with your classes is false.  Perhaps it isn't that relevant.

Comment: I think my statement was true since I wrote "the general $A$ of this kind", but I guess that wasn't very clear. I'll edit it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a basis for NS$(A)$. It's enough to show that $L := 2E + 2E'$ is $\pi^*M$ for some line bundle $M$ on $A$.  This is true if and only if $\ker \pi$ is contained in $K(L)$ and is isotropic for the Riemann pairing $e^L$ on $K(L) \times K(L)$.  Here, $K(L)$ is the kernel of the map from $E \times E'$ to its dual determined by $L$.  Mumford's abelian varieties book is the reference for all of this (chapter 23 I think).

In this case you can compute the Riemann pairing pretty easily in terms of the usual Weil pairings $e_2$ on $E[2]$ and $E'[2]$.  If you choose a basis $P = (p,p')$ and $Q = (q,q')$ of $\ker \pi$, then you need to check that $e^L(P,Q) = 1$. Properties of Riemann pairings imply that $$e^L(P,Q) = e_2(p,q)e_2(p',q') = (-1)(-1) = 1,$$
so it's true.

There is probably a more elementary way to show what you want, but this approach works for more general quotients.